# How to show active userlist in chat application using angular.js , socket.io, node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to build a chat application using AngularJS and Socket.io.
The status of my assignment is it sends and receives messages from different user. Users have to input their name to get access to the chatbox. The messages appear with corresponding their user in mongo terminal.

The problem is that I want to  show the active users in a list beside my chatbox and  in chat body I want to show the messages with the corresponding user.

**code: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='chatApp'>

<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angularfiles/chatexpress.js"></script>
    <style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller='chatController'>
    <!--<form >-->
    <!--     <p> Enter your name</p>-->
    <!--     <input type="text" ng-model="Myname"/>-->
    <!--    <button ng-show="!$scope.toggle" ng-click="su">Submit</button>-->
    <!-- </form>-->
    <form ng-submit="setName()">
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="Myname" placeholder="Your Name">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="!$scope.toggle" ng-click="$scope.toggle=true">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class='container' ng-class="{'hidden':!$scope.toggle}">
        <div class=' row'>
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-md-2'>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <h5>Active User</h5>
                        <li ng-repeat="user in userlist">{{$scope.user.name}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-8 col-md-6'>
                <div class='panel panel-success'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <span class="label label-success">Movie</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <!--<ul id="messages">-->
                        <p ng-repeat="msg in msgs track by $index">{{msg}}</p>
                        <!--</ul>-->
                    </div>
                    <!--<form action="">-->
                    <!--    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />-->
                    <!--    <button>Send</button>-->
                    <!--</form>-->
                    <div class='panel-footer'>
                        <form name='chatform' data-ng-submit="sendMsg()" <label for="chatform">
                            <h5>Your writing here</h5></label>
                            <input type="text" name="chatinput" class="form-control" id="chatinput" data-ng-model='text' />
                            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>-->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<script>-->
    <!--    var socket = io.connect();-->
    <!--    $('form').submit(function() {-->
    <!--        socket.emit('chat messages', $('#m').val());-->
    <!--    });-->
    <!--    socket.on('message', function(msg) {-->
    <!--        console.log("testing " + msg);-->
    <!--        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));-->
    <!--    });-->
    <!--</script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

**controller code**

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', []);
app.factory('socket', function() {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return socket;
})

app.controller('chatController', function($scope, socket) {

    $scope.msgs = [];
    $scope.userlist = [];
    $scope.toggle = false;
    // $scope.Myname='';
    $scope.roomname = '';
    $scope.text = '';
    var info = {};


    $scope.sendMsg = function() {
        //console.log("in send message option");
        console.log($scope.Myname);
        info.name = $scope.Myname;

        info.message = $scope.text;
        info.room = $scope.roomname;
        socket.emit('send msg', info);
        //$scope.text='';

    }

    socket.on('newmsg', function(data) {

        // console.log("in getmessage"+ data);
        $scope.msgs.push(data);
        $scope.$digest();

    });



    socket.on('userlist', function(names) {
        $scope.userlist.push(names);
        // console.log("update"+$scope.userlist.names);

        $scope.$apply();

        console.log("update" + $scope.userlist.names);
    });


    socket.on('connect', function() {


        $scope.setName();

        console.log("in setname")
    })


    $scope.setName = function setName() {
        socket.emit('addedName', $scope.Myname);
        console.log("Emitting from name" + $scope.Myname);
    }
})
```

**server sidecode**

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var async = require('async');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chatexpressdb',function(err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("MongoDB is connected");
    }


});

var chatSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String},
    msg: String,
    room: String,
    time:{type:Date,default:Date.now()}

});


var ChatModel=mongoose.model("Message",chatSchema)




//
// ## SimpleServer `SimpleServer(obj)`
//
// Creates a new instance of SimpleServer with the following options:
//  * `port` - The HTTP port to listen on. If `process.env.PORT` is set, _it overrides this value_.
//
var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);
var io = socketio.listen(server);
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'/bower_components')));
var messages=[];
var sockets=[];
var user=[];


io.on('connection',function(socket)
{
    console.log('User is connected');
   /* socket.on('disconnect',function()
    {
        //console.log('User is disconnected');

    });*/











    socket.on('send msg',function(data)
    {
        console.log('chat message is'+ ':'+data.message);







        var savedMsg=new ChatModel();
        savedMsg.name=data.name;
        savedMsg.msg=data.message;

        savedMsg.save(function(err)
        {
            if(err){
                throw err;

            }
            else
            {

                io.sockets.emit('newmsg' ,data.message);

            }


        });

        //now broadcast part
    //   io.sockets.emit('getmsg' ,data,function(error,callback){
    //         console.log(error);

    //     });
        console.log("next io emit");
    }




    );



    socket.on('addedName',function(Myname)
    {


        console.log("Recieving Name" +Myname);
        socket.set(Myname,String(Myname||'Guest'),function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                throw err;
            }
            else
            {
                 console.log("updating Name"+ Myname);

            updateName();
            }
        })

    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(socket), 1);
      updateName();
    });



    // function UpdateName()
    // {
    //     io.sockets.emit('username',chatname);

    // }


    function updateName() {
  async.map(
    sockets,
    function (socket, callback) {
      socket.get('name', callback);
      console.log("setting update")
    },
    function (err, names) {
        if(err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
      broadcast('userlist', names);
    }
  );
}

function broadcast(event, data) {
  sockets.forEach(function (socket) {

              //console.log("setting broadcast");
              socket.emit(event, data);
              console.log("setting broadcast"+data);
              //console.log("setting broadcast");
  });
}






}
);


// function updateName() {
//   async.map(
//     sockets,
//     function (socket, callback) {
//       socket.get('name', callback);
//       console.log("setting update")
//     },
//     function (err, names) {
//         if(err)
//         {
//             throw err;
//         }
//       broadcast('userlist', names);
//     }
//   );
// }


// function broadcast(event, data) {
//   sockets.forEach(function (socket) {

//               socket.emit(event, data);
//               console.log("setting broadcast");
//   });
// }


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log("Chat server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
```

Comment: umm thank you for your reply sorry for that i forgot to upload my server side code here is it . where could i change the code if you explain me kindly that will be very helpful for me thanks –

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a server-side userlist, when a user signs in, then they'll be added, on drop/disconnect removed...

When the userlist changes, send a message from the server with either the full list, or modifications to the clients...

on the client-side you'll need to apply the changes to the scope, and apply those changes for a re-render of the component in question.

Comment: umm thank you for your reply  sorry  for that i forgot  to  upload my server side code  here is it . where  could i change  the  code  if you explain me kindly that will be very helpful for me thanks